# Restkit [NSManagedObject managedObjectContext] returns different instances

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, restkit

I have serious problems since I migrated my core data logic to RKManagedObjectStore. I setup a NSFetchedResultsController with the context set to [NSManagedObject managedObjectContext] within the main thread in the view controller:

```
assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [NSManagedObject managedObjectContext];
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:[Item fetchRequest] managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
```

I insert objects in the context like this:

```
Item* item = [Item object];
item.name = @"Foo";
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore save];
```

But the fetched results controller doesn't get notified of the changes. Thus I registered a notification manually:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSLog(@"Context changed");

    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

This should really not be necessary I think, since RKManagedObjectStore merges changes across different contexts. Second, for deleting the Item object I tried

```
[item deleteEntity];
```

This produced an error saying that the object cannot be deleted within another context. This is obviously true, but **WHY** the hell is the context not the same instance for the Main Thread? I call the following also inside the view controller just before deleting en entity:

```
assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
NSManagedObjectContext* sameContext1 = [NSManagedObject managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObjectContext* sameContext2 = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext;
assert(sameContext1 == sameContext2); //FAILS
```

Looking at RKManagedObjectStore's **managedObjectContext** getter Implementation which is called when using [NSManagedObject managedObjectContext], the same instance per thread should be returned:

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext {
    NSMutableDictionary* threadDictionary = [[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary];
    NSManagedObjectContext* backgroundThreadContext = [threadDictionary objectForKey:RKManagedObjectStoreThreadDictionaryContextKey];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally tracked it down that nasty bug after hours of debugging. The problem is that `RKObjectManager` holds a reference to `RKManagedObjectStore`. But somehow when using ARC that reference is not kept in the `[RKObjectManager sharedManager]` instance and is being deallocated. That causes flushing of the thread local cache. Therefore managed object context merging is not working because on every access a new managed context is created. The fix is easy. Just keep a strong reference to the `RKManagedObjectStore` in your App Delegate and you're done.